# Change paragraph direction in Windows wordpad for right to left languages

Tags: windows, text-editors, localization, right-to-left, wordpad

In Microsoft Windows default Wordpad there is no button to switch directions between ltr/rtl paragraphs for right to left languages such as Persian and Arabic.

How should I change direction when I want to have multiple directions in the same file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no button or menu option to change right to left direction in Windows 7 Wordpad. In toolbar you can only find alignment buttons which is not useful in this case. But still the worpad support windows global hotkey for switching between right-to-left and left-to-right directions.

In any paragraph in Wordpad you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left Shift</kbd> to change direction.

---

to set a paragraph direction to:

- **Right to left: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>**
- **Left to right: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>**

Comment: This applies to Windows 10, too.

Comment: This applies to Windows 11, as well.